# How to print, write, or export princomp results to a csv file

Tags: r, csv

Using princomp, results are not stored as a dataframe, e.g, running "summary(module_LS9)" is displayed in the console as table. What's the code to create a csv file or any table that I can format the output in Excel or Word?

I tried:

- sink("summary_module_LS9.csv")
- summary(module_LS9)
- sink()

This does create a csv file, but the values are not separated by commas.

Tried also:

```
write.table(summary(module_LS9), file = "module_LS9_sum.csv", sep = ",", quote = FALSE, row.names = F)
```

Got:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"summary.princomp"’ to a data.frame
```

Appreciate your time to help!

Comment: If you inspect `str(summary(module_LS9))` you will see it's a list. Try to study the code in `getAnywhere("print.summary.princomp")` and see if you can adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of these suggestions-
1.Use the package `XLConnect` which allows you to write R output to Excel files.
Here's an example, where I write a model and send the summary to excel:

```
    library(XLConnect)
    dat <- data.frame(rsp = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                      pred1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                      pred2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1))
    model <- lm(rsp ~ pred1 + pred2, data = dat)
    writeWorksheetToFile("model1.xlsx", 
                     data = summary(dat), 
                     sheet = "summary", 
                     header = TRUE,
                     clearSheets = TRUE)
```

2.If you are only trying to export the output of summary function, try this

`write.csv(summary(data_frame),"output.csv")`


3. Use the package `stargazer`. It doesn't export output to Excel, but makes nice HTML, Latex and ASCII tables which can be copy pasted to Excel.It also allows to quickly create a table which compares different models.

More info: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf

Comment: Thanks! 2) This solution is all what I need but it returns: Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :  cannot coerce class ‘"summary.princomp"’ to a data.frame 3) stargazer too complicated, need this as CSV to format in Word. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `as.data.frame` method you can use:

```
as.data.frame.summary.princomp <- function(x, ...) {
  vars <- x$sdev^2
  vars <- vars/sum(vars)
  type.convert(
    as.data.frame(
      rbind(`Standard deviation` = x$sdev, `Proportion of Variance` = vars, 
          `Cumulative Proportion` = cumsum(vars))
    )
  )
}
```

Call it like this:

```
res <- as.data.frame(summary(princomp(USArrests, cor = TRUE)))
#                          Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3     Comp.4
#Standard deviation     1.5748783 0.9948694 0.5971291 0.41644938
#Proportion of Variance 0.6200604 0.2474413 0.0891408 0.04335752
#Cumulative Proportion  0.6200604 0.8675017 0.9566425 1.00000000
```

A data.frame can be exported with `write.csv` as usual.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tried it, got: Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list', this finally works for me:  x <- summary(module_LS9)
vars <- x$sdev^2
vars <- vars/sum(vars)
write.table(rbind("Standard deviation" = x$sdev, "Proportion of
Variance" = vars,
                  "Cumulative Proportion" = cumsum(vars)), file="PCA_sum_module_LS9.csv", sep=",")

Comment: I don't see how my code would even call `is.finite`. How did you call it?

Comment: I must assume a minimal understanding when writing my answers. Anyway, if `module_LS9` is the result of a call to the `princomp` function, you would substitute it for `princomp(USArrests, cor = TRUE)`.

Comment: Sorry, overlapped answers, I understand that part of course. This is what I ran: > res <- as.data.frame(summary(princomp(module_LS9, cor = TRUE)))
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list' (using RStudio)

Comment: You said module_LS9 is a princomp object. Why are you then calling princomp on it?

Comment: Roland: "module_LS9" is a result of: module_LS9<-princomp(formula = ~., data = data_INST_AB_LS9, cor = TRUE, na.action=na.exclude); 
All I wanted was to print the table shown in the console to a file as csv, values separated by commas. I tried your code: res <- as.data.frame(summary(princomp(formula = ~., data = data_INST_AB_LS9, cor = TRUE, na.action=na.exclude))) which returns an error "cannot coerce class ‘"summary.princomp"’ to a data.frame." That is why I replaced "USArrests" with the name of my module_LS9 object, which returns the is.finite error. Thanks again!

Comment: Just do `res <- as.data.frame(summary(module_LS9))` **after** defining the `as.data.frame.summary.princomp` function as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to save the summary, but you can obtain the same table saving a csv file of

```
comp<-princomp(base,cor=T)
var<-comp$sdev^2
write.csv(var,file="variance.csv")
```

Then go to the csv file, and calculate directly in excel the rest, is just the estandar desviation, proportion of variance from each one, and the cummulative proportion.